# Find method through Reflection by creating a List<T> of the right type at runtime for CreateInstance argument

Tags: c#, reflection, type-conversion

I have a base class (`MyBase`) with lots of possible derived classes (in this example, `MyDerived` and `MyDerived2`).  Along the way a `List<MyBase>` is handed off to another class, and then later on that class needs to call a constructor of yet another class... which constructor is called is based entirely on what's in the `List`.

I can use Reflection to find the constructor, but only if somewhere along the way I do something like:

```
var r = baseList.ConvertAll(x => (MyDerived1)x);
```

So that `r` contains a `List<MyDerived1>` and I can find the constructor through Reflection.  This is silly, of course, because I could also just bake-in the constructor since I'm bothering to bake in `MyDerived1` in that `ConvertAll` statement.  But this is one derived class, and I have dozens.

What I want to do is have the method `RunTest()` call the right constructor based entirely on what it finds in the `List<MyBase>` at runtime.  Looking at the first object in the list is fine, as a practical matter since they'll always be all of the same type.

Is this possible?  How?

```
namespace Classtest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Test t = new Test( new List<MyBase>() {
                            new MyDerived1(),
                            new MyDerived1() } );
            t.RunTest();
        }
    }

    public class Test
    {
        List<MyBase> baseList;
        public Test(List<MyBase> bl)
        {
            baseList = bl;
        }
        public void RunTest()
        {
            // I would like the CreateInstance to figure out which constructor
            //    to call based on what it finds in baseList,
            //   without having to indicate "MyDerived1" here.
            // This works, but I'd rather have it figure this out at
            //   runtime for every single possible derived class...
            var r = baseList.ConvertAll(x => (MyDerived1)x);  
            Object o = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(CallMe), 
                        new object[] { r });
        }
    }

    public class CallMe
    {
        public CallMe(List<MyDerived1> myDerived)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Found it.");
        }
        public CallMe(List<MyDerived2> myDerived)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Wrong one!");
        }
    }

    public class MyBase
    { }
    public class MyDerived1 : MyBase
    { }
    public class MyDerived2 : MyBase
    { }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to constraint all derive types to have a default (parameter-less) constructors? Or you want to give them freedom? I think some serializers constraint on having one. When you don't have one and you try to use them (serializers), they throw an exception on you face.

Comment: Are you just asking to find out the `T` in a `List<T>`?

Comment: It's really hard to understand this question, maybe because of my poor English. I read this post again and again, hope I haven't misunderstood your question.

Comment: Danny: I'm a native English speaker and I can't understand it either.

Comment: You should reconsider your design.

Comment: @SLaks:  Every design should be reconsidered.  Sometimes it's not mine to design, oftentimes it's someone else's code, and more often than not it works just fine the way it is.  In this case, it's all three.  I'm just trying to save some programmer headaches staring at a giant switch/case block of (nearly) duplicate code and the maintenance of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`MakeGenericType()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype.aspx) to create a `List<T>` with the correct generic type:

```
public void RunTest()
{
    // This method is creating a new list by doing the following:
    // var r = new List<baseList[0].GetType>(
    //             baseList.Cast<baseList[0].GetType()>);

    var elementType = baseList[0].GetType();

    // Get the System.Linq.Enumerable Cast<elementType> method.
    var castMethod = typeof(Enumerable)
                   .GetMethod("Cast", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
                   .MakeGenericMethod(elementType);

    // Create a List<elementType>, using the Cast method to populate it.
    var listType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(new [] { elementType });
    var r = Activator.CreateInstance(listType, 
            new [] {castMethod.Invoke(null, new [] {baseList})});

    Object o = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(CallMe), 
               new [] { r });
}
```

If your `CallMe` constructors could be changed to take an `IEnumerable<>` parameter instead of `List<>`, then you could simplify `RunTest()` by removing the `List<>` creation:

```
public void RunTest()
{
    var elementType = baseList[0].GetType();

    // Get the System.Linq.Enumerable Cast<elementType> method.
    var castMethod = typeof(Enumerable)
                   .GetMethod("Cast", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
                   .MakeGenericMethod(elementType);

    Object o = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(CallMe), 
               new [] { castMethod.Invoke(null, new[] {baseList}) });
}
```

Comment: I like this.  Cleaner than Tom's but does involve copying to a new array.  Not sure which I like better.

Comment: @clintp Tom's solution will also create a new `List<>` in the call to `ToList()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void RunTest()
{ 
    // it seems like you would want to run the following using reflection...
    // var myBaseList = this.baseList.OfType<this.baseList[0].GetType()>().ToList();

    Type[] genericTypeArray = new Type[] { this.baseList[0].GetType() };

    // call OfType to get IEnumerable<this.baseList[0].GetType()>
    MethodInfo ofTypeMethodInfo = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods().Where(d => d.Name == "OfType").First();
    ofTypeMethodInfo = ofTypeMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(genericTypeArray);
    object myBaseEnumerable = ofTypeMethodInfo.Invoke(null, new object[] { this.baseList });

    // call ToList to get List<this.baseList[0].GetType()>
    MethodInfo toListMethodInfo = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods().Where(d => d.Name == "ToList").First();
    toListMethodInfo = toListMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(genericTypeArray);
    object myBaseList = toListMethodInfo.Invoke(null, new object[] { myBaseEnumerable });

    Object o = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(CallMe), new object[] { myBaseList }); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If CreateInstance can't find the right constructor, try typeof(...).GetConstructor() and pass in the right types. This will give you the right ctor, which you can invoke. I don't think there's another, non-reflection way, LINQ Cast<> and similar methods require the type to be statically known or given as a type parameter, which is not the case when you have a list which could contain anything.

UPDATE: Oh, it won't work, you can't pass a List<derived> to a List<base> constructor. Here's what you need: you need to call Cast<> with reflection. typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("Cast").MakeGenericMethod(list[0].GetType()). Then, you have a list with the correct type, so no need for constructor reflection, Activator will work with this.

Comment: `CreateInstance` with a `List<MyBase>` won't find a constructor.  So that's right out.  "try typeof...GetConstructor... and pass in the right types" is the whole problem here.  I need a type of `List<MyDerived1>` generated at *runtime* in order to find the constructor.  That's the problem.

Comment: It's easy: typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(list[0].GetType)

Answer (score 0):

```
public void RunTest()         
{            
 if (baseList.Count > 0)
 {
   Type ctorParam = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(baseList[0].GetType());
   object instance = typeof(CallMe).GetConstructor(new Type[] { ctorParam })
                            .Invoke(new object[] { baseList });   
 }
}
```

Comment: Not quite.  When the constructor is called.... 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Classtest.MyBase]' cannot be converted to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Classtest.MyDerived1]'.